# Qué es una matriz de una dimensión en Java

Tags: java, jframe, matriz

Tengo esta actividad. Y no logro entender que es una matriz de una dimensión. Todo esto es dentro de un JFrame.

Realizar una aplicación en Java que permita ingresar 10 notas en cajas de texto separadas, un boton que al ser presionado tome las notas de las cajas de texto y las ingrese en un vector (matriz de una dimensión). Luego calcule el promedio de esas notas, encuentre la nota más alta y la más baja. Por último agregar a la ventana de la aplicación 3 etiquetas de texto (label) que muestren estos tres resultados. Agregar un 4to label que indique si está aprobado si el promedio es >= 6 o desaprobado si el promedio es <6. Agregar un botón que borre todos los campos y le ingrese el número 0 (cero).

Lo que yo tengo es esto:

```
    int a = Integer.parseInt(Text1.getText());
    int b = Integer.parseInt(Text2.getText());
    int c = Integer.parseInt(Text3.getText());
    int d = Integer.parseInt(Text4.getText());
    int e = Integer.parseInt(Text5.getText());
    int f = Integer.parseInt(Text6.getText());
    int g = Integer.parseInt(Text7.getText());
    int h = Integer.parseInt(Text8.getText());
    int i = Integer.parseInt(Text9.getText());
    int j = Integer.parseInt(Text10.getText());
    int Prom;
    
    Prom=a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j;
    
    Lblprom.setText(String.valueOf(Prom));
```

Mi pregunta es: Puedo abreviar esto usando un for? Al hacer esto, ¿estoy usando una matriz de una dimensión?

Saludos!!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Una matriz de una dimension (array o vector) es una matriz, que solo tiene una dimension... No termino de entender tu pregunta...

Comment: Ya lo edito! Disculpáme. Mi idea no era que ustedes resuelvan el ejercicio. Mi idea era que me pudieran explicar como incorporar una matriz

Comment: @gbianchi Listo, está modificado!

Comment: las respuestas son no y no...

Comment: sabes escribir un array? como se define un array?

Comment: y la primera.. tal vez, si tenes un metodo para recorrer los objetos que estan dentro del jframe la respuesta sea si.. pero de eso no estoy totalmente seguro....

Comment: Jajaja, bien. No, qué es un array?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128216/discussion-between-inkinvissible-and-gbianchi).

Comment: bueno.. para eso esta google no? tambien el [chat]...

Comment: Está en la pregunta. ".. las ingrese en un vector (matriz de una dimensión)."  A propósito, en Java, un Vector no es el mismo como un array.

Comment: @Duston en Java, como en cualquier otro lenguaje un arreglo, matriz y vector son la misma cosa. Esto se debe a que es un typo de estructura de datos. Ahora bien, en Java hay una clase que se llama `Vector` que en una implementación de la interfaz `List` que utiliza un array para almacenar los datos (al igual que `ArrayList`).

Comment: Esta pregunta carece de un ejemplo mínimo y verificable. El ejercicio pide que los valores de los campos de texto sean recogidos en una matriz, vector o array al hacer clic en un botón. ¿Dónde está ese botón en tu programa? Tampoco tienes declarada la matriz, vector o array que recogerá los valores de los campos de texto cuando se haya presionado en el botón. Tampoco aparece clara cuál será la lógica para recoger los datos, por ejemplo, ¿se pulsará 1 sola vez en el botón y se recogerán todos los valores de los campos de texto o cada campo de texto tendrá al lado su botón p/ introducir el dato?